# Mongoose aggregate until sum of documents is equal to a certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

What pipeline can i use to select all ids until i hit the sum of `180` and get the _ids. Below is a sample of the data that i've filtered out already. In this case it should select the first two items.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6048b2b190422d0066d90740",
        "Code": "A0ABI61YH",
        "Amount": 100
    },
    {
        "_id": "6048b3cc7e4b350072424f4c",
        "Code": "A0ABEAXX6",
        "Amount": 100
    },
    {
        "_id": "6048b5167e4b350072424f50",
        "Code": "A0ABCENPD",
        "Amount": 100
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is there any straight way to achieve this, if you really want to then try, this will only work when your data size below 16MB, because we are going to group your documents in a document in array, second this may cause the performance issues,

- `$group` by null and group all documents and required fields (`_id`, `Amount`) in `result`
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `result` array,

  - `initialValue` declare initial value for `Amount` is 0 and `result` is []
  - `in` check condition if initialValue's Amount is less than 180 then concat current object's _id and initialValue's _ids using `$concatArrays` and sum current object's Amount and initialValue's Amount, otherwise return same value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      result: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          Amount: "$Amount"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      result: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$result",
          initialValue: { Amount: 0, _ids: [] },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $lt: ["$$value.Amount", 180] },
              {
                _ids: { $concatArrays: ["$$value._ids", ["$$this._id"]] },
                Amount: { $sum: ["$$value.Amount", "$$this.Amount"] }
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0Z7G3a9x0u1)

Comment: Thank you you're a life saver. This will work for now as i check if there's a way to use $accumulator in conjuction with this.

Comment: @DavidMeck i think $accumulator is little heavy because of JS code executing for each document, anyway have you solved your query, if it does then please mark to accept the answer with green tick.